# Uploading data type of Map or Array to Firestore database to match Firestore map and array type

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have a Map of type `Map<String, String>` and I am trying to upload it to Firestore to match the map datatype available as a field. See image below. 
[image]

I have tried using the toString method for the map class and assigning it to a field but it shows up as a long string rather than a map, see code snippet below

```
Firestore.instance.collection('/mycollection').add({
  'mapData' : myMap.toString(), // myMap.toString() = {data: test, data2: name}
}).then((onValue) {
  // do something
}).catchError((e) {
  print(e);
});
```

The above snippet uploads the to string value of `myMap` as a string and assigns it to `mapdata`. It does not send the data in the map format to Firestore

Any ideas on how to send a type of `Map<string, string>` to Firestore to map the type of `map` that Firestore provides ? And also from `List` to Firestore `array`

Comment: I take it that you already tried to use `myMap` directly as the field value for `mapData`, and it didn't do what you expect?

Comment: Nah I didnt actually, I just did and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will work

```
Firestore.instance.collection('/mycollection').add({
  'mapData' : myMap,
}).then((onValue) {
  // do something
}).catchError((e) {
  print(e);
});
```

Comment: This will likely not create a field of type object as is shown in the screenshot.  The document in the screenshot has a single field `thisMap`, and it contains an object with three properties.

Comment: @DougStevenson You are right. Missed the small detail. Let me rethink

Comment: You were right, that actually worked, thank you, it sent it to the Firestore as a map

Answer (score -1):

**Uploading data type of Map or Array to Firestore database to match Firestore map and array type**
**Ans:** using Angular

```
    rate: any = [];

    constructor(
        public db: AngularFirestore,
      ) {}



   addnew() {
     try {
        this.db.collection('try').add({ 
           sharedWith: [{ who: "me", when: new Date() }]
          })
      }
      catch (error) {
        console.log('Error', error);
      }
    }

**Add Map data Type To firestore**


addnew() {
     try {
        this.db.collection('try').add({
           sharedWith: { who: "me", when: new Date() }
        })
      }
      catch (error) {
        console.log('Error', error);
      }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see a Map object